# Why do i get an Inflate exception on the emulator but not on my Droid?

Tags: android, exception, stack, inflate

My code runs fine on my Motorola Droid but when i run it on the emulator i get this stack trace:

```
07-05 14:29:23.035: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught      exception
07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity        ComponentInfo{com.thinknao.wordlands/com.thinknao.wordlands.OptionsPage}:         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)

07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)

07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:65)

07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-05 14:29:23.075: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(237):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to be exact without seeing your code and layout, but you are running out of memory. It looks to be concerned with the loading of a bitmap object, one that is referenced on line 16 of your layout file.

I would suggest that either you are using a very large image file; you are using lots of images; or a combination of the two.

The reason that it runs on the Droid but not on the emulator is, most likely, that the emulator has been configured with less memory than the phone. You can change your emulator settings in the AVD manager.

Comment: i have a lot of images in the project but this page is the options page. it only has 10 pictures max. none of them are very large

Comment: it works on android 2.1 but not 1.6. i guess i have to change my project to comply. does 2.1 support more memory or is it just better?

Comment: The OS itself doesn't support any more or less memory. The image handling is likely to be more efficient on a later version, and older hardware is likely to have less memory than newer hardware. 1.6 and earlier accounts for less than 5% of devices according to http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html.